# Wait for the result of an database update before moving to next statement

Tags: java, servlets

I want my servlet to wait for the result of a database update before moving to the next line.
I have the following code snippet:

```
//wait for this to finish and get the status
status=profiledao.updateProfile(profile);

//then execute this statement
httpresponse.getWriter().print(fileName);
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The default behavior is what you want.  Java calls are blocking unless you specifically make them non-blocking (e.g., an EJB method marked @Asynchronous).

Comment: Is it not waiting with the current code?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running this line asynchronously with additional unshown code, the code you have posted will do exactly what you are intending to do in a normal Java environment.

If you are running this asynchronously and want to continue doing so while still accomplishing the task you are talking about, you want what is called a Promise

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::sendMsg)  
             .thenAccept(this::notify);
```

This code is a very very simple way of doing this in an asynchronous setting, however, if the code you have shown is Synchronous then this is not needed.